# How to yield item only after all links have been followed in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The original code:

```
class HomepageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'homepage_spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        ...

    def parse(self, response):
        # harvest some data from response
        item = ...

        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://detail-page",
            callback=self.parse_details,
            cb_kwargs={"item": item}
        )

    def parse_details(self, response, item):
        # harvest details
        ...
        yield item
```

This is the standard way to follow links on a page. However it has a flaw: if there is an http error (e.g. 503) or connection error when following the 2nd URL, `parse_details` is never called, and `yield item` is never executed. And so all data is lost.

Changed code:

```
class HomepageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'homepage_spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        ...

    def parse(self, response):
        # harvest some data from response
        item = ...

        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://detail-page",
            callback=self.parse_details,
            cb_kwargs={"item": item}
        )
        yield item

    def parse_details(self, response, item):
        # harvest details
        ...
```

Changed code does not work, it seems `yield item` is immediately executed before `parse_details` is run (perhaps due to Twisted framework, this behavior is different from what's expected in `asynio` library) and so the item is always yielded with incomplete data.

How to make sure the `yield item` is executed after all links are followed? regardless of success or failure. Is something like

```
    res1 = scrapy.Request(...)
    res2 = scrapy.Request(...)

    yield scrapy.join([res1, res2])  # block until both urls are followed?
    yield item
```

possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can send the failed requests to a function (whenever an Error happens),yield the item from there.

```
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
class HomepageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'homepage_spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        ...

    def parse(self, response):
        # harvest some data from response
        item = ...

        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://detail-page",
            callback=self.parse_details,
            meta={"item": item},
            errback=self.my_handle_error
        )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        # harvest details
        ...
        yield item

    def my_handle_error(self,failure,item):
         response = failure.value.response
        print(f"Error on {response.url}")
        #you can do much depth error checking here to see what type of failure like DNSlookup,timeouterror,httperror ...
        yield item
```

second Edit to yield the item

```
yield scrapy.Request(
                "https://detail-page",
                callback=self.parse_details,
                cb_kwargs={"item": item},
                errback=errback=lambda failure, item=item: self.my_handle_error(failure, item)
            )

def my_handle_error(self,failure,item):
    yield item
```

Comment: just want to make a note, item is not passed into `my_handle_error`, and errback does not receive kwargs from cb_kwargs. The only way to pass item in is via `request.meta`. It's quite a hassle, it did solve my problem, though not addressing the question anyway.